# When I enter the "pod install" command "[!] Error installing OneSignalXCFramework

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal

I'm trying to develop ios with Flutter. After pod install error "[!] Error installing OneSignalXCFramework
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK.git /var/folders/7g/pwrb7ks91djfkg0cj622j_2h0000gn/T/d20240315-12133-a0osgm --template= --single I get the error "-branch --depth 1 --branch 5.1.3"

Answer (score 0):

just change onesignal_flutter package to this version

onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.3

and run pod update

works fine for me.